# Jenkins - Microsoft Teams webhooks - Failed to post data to webhook Stream closed

Tags: jenkins, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am attempting to use the Office 365 Connector plugin for Jenkins in order to push messages to Microsoft Teams. When I run a simple test, I receive the message below. Even though my Jenkins HTTP Proxy Configuration is testing to external sites ok within the Plugin Manager, I'm thinking my work proxy is causing problems. Would this error message match up to that assumption?

Thanks

```
Using proxy authentication (user=[domain]\[user])
Failed to post data to webhook - 
https://outlook.office.com/webhook/[removed]/JenkinsCI/[removed]
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:177)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:115)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(HttpMethodBase.java:697)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBodyAsString(HttpMethodBase.java:810)
at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.HttpWorker.run(HttpWorker.java:83)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```